# degrees of freedom in estimation of sigma squared (HLM)

Tags: multilevel-analysis, degrees-of-freedom

In HLM software, when running 2 level null model, its come out

> There are no degrees of freedom to estimate sigma_squared. Set sigma_squared to a constant, or delete one or more of the random effects from the model.

I trying to change level 2 variables to nominal variables, but it didn't help.

Can anyone share the experiences to solve this problem?